# Why does my app rotate without animation?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

I have an app with an animated splashscreen and a main interface.

To transition from the splashscreen to the main interface I used this code:

```
presentViewController(mainViewController, true) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController = mainViewController
}
```

But apparently this method ruins autorotation (took me a while to find that one). Now I have the issue that this autorotation is not with animation.

I guess this is not with animation because the old viewcontroller still lives below the other viewcontroller and it just forwards the new orientation.

How can I *properly* transition from one viewcontroller to the next while being able to destroy the old viewcontroller and keep rotation?

**Edit:** I noticed that my homescreen rotates when I close my app (from its startup orientation to the orientation the app was in when I closed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to UIWindow documentation;

> If the window has an existing view hierarchy, the old views are
>   removed before the new ones are installed.

Source Link -> [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwindow#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController)

So, system automatically destroy while decide to no longer need your first RootViewController. You can handle transition like this;

```
if var topRootController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    while (topRootController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topRootController = topRootController.presentedViewController!
    }
    topRootController.presentViewController(homeController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This has the same result (rotation occurs without animation) and prints this: `Warning: Attempt to present <MenuViewController: 0x12d9cd920> on <SplashScreenViewController: 0x12d857740> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Still no animation.

Comment: So I found the issue (but I don't really understand why this gives that problem). I have a storyboard that is set in the `Info.plist` as the main interface (I ignored this, because I don't need it). In my `AppDelegate.finishedLaunching` I create a new window and set its root view controller, which I then set as key window. Removing either the window setting in `AppDelegate` or `Info.plist` resolves the issue.

Comment: @vrwim: can you repost this as an answer instead of a comment? This was the right solution to my (identical) problem. How can this disable all rotation animations? O.o Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fruitcoder Done. I don't really know why this disables the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Kemal said, I have found my specific issue:

I don't really understand why this gives that problem. I have a storyboard that is set in the `Info.plist` as the main interface (I ignored this, because I don't need it). In my `AppDelegate.finishedLaunching` I create a new window and set its root view controller, which I then set as key window. Removing either the window setting in `AppDelegate` or `Info.plist` resolves the issue.